# Randomly sample groups of rows linked by unique column values with the same # of observations

Tags: r

I am trying to randomly sample a full data set where each row represents an observation on a binary response of present or absent based on a series of covariates. All covariates are grouped by having 1 row representing "present" with 5 linked rows representing "absent". In the data, this 1:5 ratio equals 6 total rows linked by a unique ID number (e.g., the column ID with a value of 1 has 6 linked rows which are represented in another column "Status" as: present, absent, absent, absent, absent, absent).
I am trying to:

1. Randomly sample 60% of the unique IDs (ID column) from the total data set. I need all 6 rows within each unique ID to represent 1 random selection, but the output should include all 6 rows for that ID. The group_by function in dplyr might have a series of nested functions which can do this, but I have yet to figure it out.

This data would look like the following:
[image: Data Table example]

Below is an example of code that would work when dealing with data where each row is a unique ID (this is NOT the same format that I am trying to figure out).

```
sample.size <- floor(0.60*nrow(df))
set.seed(575)
train.1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(df)), size = sample.size)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide an [mcve]. In particular, rather than showcasing your data as an image, you should [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(your_data)` (where `your_data` is replaced with the actual name of your data frame)

Comment: @duckmayr Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I don't have a good example of what I am trying to code, thus my question here. I have added some code which works when you have single rows which are all unique, but that is not what I need to do. Please let me know if I can explain any additional details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty straightforward. The strategy I’ve used here is to get the unique IDs for sampling, then subset based on that. Below is a base R solution.

I’ve expanded the number of IDs so you can see the sampling a little better.

```r
df <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = rep(1:10, each = 6),
    status = rep(c("present", rep("absent", 5)), 10),
    Cov1 = "numbers",
    Cov2 = "numbers"
  )

head(df)
#>   ID  status    Cov1    Cov2
#> 1  1 present numbers numbers
#> 2  1  absent numbers numbers
#> 3  1  absent numbers numbers
#> 4  1  absent numbers numbers
#> 5  1  absent numbers numbers
#> 6  1  absent numbers numbers
```

```r
ids <- unique(df$ID)
sample.size <- floor(0.6*length(ids))

set.seed(1080)
train.1.ids <- sample(ids, sample.size)
train.1.ids
#> [1] 1 8 3 4 7 5
train.1 <- df[df$ID %in% train.1.ids , ]
tail(train.1)
#>    ID  status    Cov1    Cov2
#> 43  8 present numbers numbers
#> 44  8  absent numbers numbers
#> 45  8  absent numbers numbers
#> 46  8  absent numbers numbers
#> 47  8  absent numbers numbers
#> 48  8  absent numbers numbers

set.seed(1081)
train.2.ids <- sample(ids, sample.size)
train.2.ids
#> [1] 10  7  4  8  1  3
train.2 <- df[df$ID %in% train.2.ids , ]
tail(train.2)
#>    ID  status    Cov1    Cov2
#> 55 10 present numbers numbers
#> 56 10  absent numbers numbers
#> 57 10  absent numbers numbers
#> 58 10  absent numbers numbers
#> 59 10  absent numbers numbers
#> 60 10  absent numbers numbers
```

You could also turn this into a function

```r
get_sample <- function(df, prop = 0.6, seed){
  ids <- unique(df$ID)
  ids <- order(ids)
  sample.size <- floor(prop*length(ids))

  set.seed(seed)
  train.1.ids <- sample(ids, sample.size)
  ## just to illustrate the IDs sampled
  print(train.1.ids)
  train.1 <- df[df$ID %in% train.1.ids , ]
  
  return(train.1)
}

train.3 <- get_sample(df, prop = 0.6, seed = 1)
#> [1] 9 4 7 1 2 5
train.4 <- get_sample(df, prop = 0.4, seed = 2)
#> [1] 5 6 9 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have tried using this but it does not seem to be drawing a random sample? In other words, if I wanted a unique random sampling to create 3 different data sets (i.e., train.1, train.2, and train.3), how should this be coded?

Comment: We use `set.seed` at the start to make sure the same sample is taken. You could change the seed between samples for reproducibility.

Comment: e.g. `set.seed(1081); train.2.ids <- sample(ids, sample.size)`

Comment: See the edits for an expanded example showing the IDs

Comment: Thank you! I am then taking this and splitting it into 2 data sets (test/train). I seem to be getting the common Error: in `[.default`(xj, i) : invalid subscript type 'list' message when using the code below (as adapted to your above example for train.1).               train.set.1 <- df[train.1,]
test.set.1 <- df[-train.1,]

Comment: you're trying to subset `df` by another `data.frame` (`train.1`) and R doesn't know how to handle that. You would just use the IDs again to get the test set. Specifically, the IDs that were not sampled. e.g. `test.set.1 <- df[!df$ID %in% train.1.ids , ]`

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful.